# codeigniter error loop with page redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Hello I have created an update query using a concept that if the id is valid then it should update the data otherwise it will not do so but when any of the conditions meet it redirects and says page is redirecting to the loop why is this happening so ?

Controller

```
public function confirm() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true) {
        $invc = "#".$this->input->get('id');

        if($invc == true) {
            $this->data_update->update_trans($invc);
        } else {
            redirect('home/confirm');
        }
    } else {
        redirect('user/login');
    }
}
```

Here is my model file

```
public function update_trans($invc_id) {
        $get_trans  = $this->db->get_where('transaction', array("invc_id" =>  $invc_id));
        $user_id    = $get_trans->row()->userid;
        $amount     = $get_trans->row()->ammount;

        if(!empty($user_id)) {
            $check     = $this->db->get_where('account', array("user_id" =>  $user_id));
            if($check->row()->balance == true) {
                $new_amount = ($amount + $check->row()->balance);
                $dataupdate = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'balance' => $new_amount
                );

                $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
                $this->db->update('account', $dataupdate);

                $this->db->where('invc_id', $invc_id);
                $this->db->update('transaction', array('status' => 'Confirmed'));
                redirect('home/confirm?id='.$invc_id);
            } else {

                $data1 = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'balance' => $amount
                );

                $this->db->insert('account', $data1);
                $this->db->where('invc_id', $invc_id);
                $this->db->update('transaction', array('status' => 'Confirmed'));

                redirect('home/confirm?id='.$invc_id);
            }
        } else {
            redirect('home/confirm');
        }
    }
```

And this is my view file

```
<?php
require('sidebar.php');
    ?>
        <!-- Body Content -->
        <div id="body">
        <?php 
            if($this->input->get('id') == true) {
        ?>
            <div class="msg">
                <h4>Your Payment Has been confirmed successfully</h4>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="msg">
                <h4>Payment Not confirmed</h4>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div id="break">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
```

I dont know why but it is giving me the same error This webpage has a redirect loop can anyone help me out with this please

Comment: read my article carefully i wrote  This webpage has a redirect loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function its going every time in else part (redirect('home/confirm');) so its showing error. Your function should be like this..

```
public function confirm() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true) {
        $invc = "#".$this->input->get('id');
        if($this->input->get('id')) {
            $this->data_update->update_trans($invc);
        } else {
            redirect('home/confirm');
        }
    } else {
        redirect('user/login');
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: link : http://localhost/smpanel_new/home/confirm
and same error message error : This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: This is a localhost server link.

Comment: did you echo it $this->input->get('id') and checked the is value is in it or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try your confirm() function as like that:

```
public function confirm() 
{
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true) {

        $id = intval($this->input->get('id'));
        $invc = "#".$id;

        if($id > 0) {
            $this->data_update->update_trans($invc);
        } else {
            redirect('home/confirm');
        }
    } else {
        redirect('user/login');
    }
}
```

You are expecting this `"#".$this->input->get('id')` will return you true or false.

And more if still facing same issue, than check what are you getting in `$_GET` like:

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true) {
    print_r($_GET); // will return you an array
}
```